# Inject Default value for Web-Api Method parameter when its null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, action-filter

i have a web api method something like;

```
[HttpGet, Route("users")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers([FromUri] UserSearchDto searchParams)
{}
```

the searchParams is optional parameter so when i pass no search values and use simply like http://api-uri/users it becomes null and then i have to add check in the body of method to avoid null reference exception.

is there a way using ActionFilters or something else to inject a default value for the parameter of this web api method so that i could avoid

```
if (searchParams == null){
  searchParams = new UserSearchDto ()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Honestly, what you're doing is pretty much it. If you want to make it a bit neater, yo can condense that null check into one line like so:

```
searchParams = searchParams ?? new UserSeachDto();
```